# Python - Function save list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, math

i need graph the function sigmoide en python, but i can´t save the results of my function fsig(x), in a list for create my DataFrame and plot in sns.

```
x = []
for i in range(-5, 6, 1):
  x.append(i)
print(x)


def fsig(n):  
  e = 2.718
  l = []

  for z in n:
    y = (1 / (1 + e**z))
    Y = round(y, 3)
    l.append(Y)
    print(Y)


fsig(x)


df = pd.DataFrame({'Eje X': x, 'Eje Y': l})
df


sns.lineplot(x = 'Eje X', y = 'Eje Y', data=df)
```

Comment: As far as I can understand you question, you want to plot a curve of the Sigmoid function. There are a couple of mistakes in your program. First and biggest mistake, the formula of Sigmoid function is wrong.  `(1 / (1 + e**(-z)))`. Second, you are trying to access the values of the list l, which is local to the function. What you want to do is to use return statement to get the value of that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = []
l = []
e = 2.718

for i in range(-5, 6, 1):
  x.append(i)
  x.sort(reverse=True)

for i in x:
  y =(1 / (1 + e**-i))
  l.append(y)

print(x)
print(l)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Eje X': x, 'Eje Y': l})

sns.lineplot(x = 'Eje X', y = 'Eje Y', data=df)
```

Comment: Please consider amending your answer to include a description of what you have changed.